# Figuring out the primary key when auto generated

Tags: sql, jpa, derby

This seems like it should be simple but I haven't been able to find the answer... I am using ElipseLink with Derby in an EE7 environment and have a series of tables with foreign or composite key relationships.

If there are tables A, B and C where A's primary key is auto generated. B uses it as a foreign key and C as part of a composite primary key.

How do I determine the auto generated value when it is the only guaranteed unique value in A?

My assumption was that it should be available in the Entity Manager methods somehow or direct from the property after the em.persist(entity) completes. I've confirmed that the record is created but the property remains null when I use the getter method after the persist.

Thanks in advance,
John

Comment: At the lowest level, it's Statement.getGeneratedKeys: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys() However, I think your question is really about JPA and EclipseLink, and I don't know the answer there.

Comment: @Bryan Your feedback provided a breadcrumb to help me improve my searching. I discovered that the persistence layer only populates the primary key property after a physical write to the database. This is accomplished with em.flush() and now it works great. Thanks for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With generation type IDENTITY it is recommended that persistence.xml be set to create or drop and create so that EclipseLink can create a table to track the next key.

The update to the auto generated key doesn't occur in the entity property until the physical write to the database. By using em.flush() this can be forced and the getter method will return the updated key value.